# \begin{figure}[ht] invalid

Tags: floats

I am using this template. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-journal-of-plasma-physics-jpp/mtstpytyffvy

I inserted a picture by using figure. However, it incorrectly displays [ht] on the left side of the picture and the floating point does not work correctly either. Why?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{c2.png}
\caption{error}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Why [ht] is on the left?]

The project is here with full code:

```
\documentclass{jpp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\shorttitle{XXX}
\shortauthor{XXXX}

\title{XXXX}

\author{XXXX\aff{1}
  \corresp{\email{XXX@XXX}}}

\affiliation{\aff{1}XXX}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
XXXX
\end{abstract}


\section{sample}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

https://www.overleaf.com/read/tvfnfbfmdzmj

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try without `[ht]`, as shown in the example of the template

Comment: I don't think `[ht]` is necessary.

Comment: The class uses `[tp]` as default floating specifier and has a special environment for bottom figures. So just leave out the floating specifier and the class will use what it is designed for.

Comment: I do need [ht] or it displays at the incorrect position.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Here is the full code :  https://www.overleaf.com/read/tvfnfbfmdzmj

Comment: [tp] does not work either.

Comment: @cqwrteur Don't use `[tp]`, use just nothing. The class itself makes `[tp]` the default value.

Comment: @samcarter no matter what [xxxx] i am using. The figure all displays incorrectly with [xxxx] on the left side of the picture.

Comment: @cqwrteur Don't use any `[xxx]` just `\begin{figure}` without anything else

Comment: "I do need [ht] or it displays at the incorrect position."  If you're wanting to specifically place an image, then it no longer floats, and shouldn't be in a figure environment.  If you still need a caption to make it look like a figure, look into the caption package.

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the example document which can accessed when clicking "view source" at the link your shared in your question (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-journal-of-plasma-physics-jpp/mtstpytyffvy) You should not use any overlay specifications, just write

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c2.PNG}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

From a quick look I think that the class uses `[tp]` as default and has a special environment for figures at the bottom of a page.

```
% This is file JFM2esam.tex
% first release v1.0, 20th October 1996
%       release v1.01, 29th October 1996
%       release v1.1, 25th June 1997
%       release v2.0, 27th July 2004
%       release v3.0, 16th July 2014
%       release v4.0, 15th June 2017
%   (based on JFMsampl.tex v1.3 for LaTeX2.09)
% Copyright (C) 1996, 1997, 2014, 2017 Cambridge University Press

\documentclass{jpp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{epstopdf, epsfig}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}


\shorttitle{XXX}
\shortauthor{XXXX}

\title{XXXX}

\author{XXXX\aff{1}
  \corresp{\email{XXX@XXX}}}

\affiliation{\aff{1}XXX}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
XXXX
\end{abstract}

%
% Uncomment for keywords
%\vspace{2pc}
%\noindent{\it Keywords}: XXXXXX, YYYYYYYY, ZZZZZZZZZ
%
% Uncomment for Submitted to journal title message
%\submitto{\JPA}
%
% Uncomment if a separate title page is required
%\maketitle
% 
% For two-column output uncomment the next line and choose [10pt] rather than [12pt] in the \documentclass declaration
%\ioptwocol
%

\section{sample}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c2.PNG}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

% susie put cite commands here, don't bother with citet etc just yet.
\end{document}
```

[image]